# ¿Cómo guardar un dato proveniente de otra Tabla MYSQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buen dìa, tengo un formulario para agregar registros a la tabla viajes, a continuacion las dos tablas:

[image: tablas viajes y buques]

*agregar-viaje.php*

```
<!doctype html>
<?php

include('libreria/motor.php');
require ('connection.php');
require ('libreria/verificar-usuario.php');
$est=viajes::mostrar();
$viajes=new viajes();
if($_POST){
$viajes->NROVIAJE=$_POST['NROVIAJE'];
$viajes->IMO=$_POST['IMO'];

$querybuqueimo="select NOMBRE from buques as elbuque where IMO='".$_POST['IMO']."'";
$relabuqueimo=mysql_query($querybuqueimo);
$buquedeimox=mysql_fetch_assoc($relabuqueimo);
$buquedeimo=$buquedeimox["elbuque"];

$viajes->BUQUE=$buquedeimo;
$viajes->PTOPROCEDENCIA=$_POST['PTOPROCEDENCIA'];
$viajes->PAISPROCEDENCIA=$_POST['PAISPROCEDENCIA'];
$viajes->PTODESTINO=$_POST['PTODESTINO'];
$viajes->PAISDESTINO=$_POST['PAISDESTINO'];
$viajes->OPERACION=$_POST['OPERACION'];
$viajes->CARGA=$_POST['CARGA'];
$viajes->CANTIDAD=$_POST['CANTIDAD'];
$viajes->CHARTER=$_POST['CHARTER'];
$viajes->guardar();
    }
$result = mysql_query("SELECT NOMBRE, IMO FROM buques ORDER BY NOMBRE ASC");
$opcion=' ';
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $opcion .= '<option value = "'.$row['IMO'].'">'.$row['NOMBRE'].' - IMO: '.$row['IMO'].'</option>';
}
$resultch = mysql_query("SELECT NOMBRECOMPANIA FROM clientes ORDER BY NOMBRECOMPANIA ASC");
$opcionch=' ';
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultch)){
    $opcionch .= '<option value = "'.$row['NOMBRECOMPANIA'].'">'.$row['NOMBRECOMPANIA'].'</option>';
}
$maxnroviaje=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(NROVIAJE) as maximo from viajes");
$nroviajenew=mysql_fetch_assoc($maxnroviaje);
$nroviajex=$nroviajenew["maximo"];
$nroviajex++;

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Agregar Viaje</title>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
<div class="form-group">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="NROVIAJE">Número de Viaje:</label>
    <input name="NROVIAJE" type="number" id="NROVIAJE" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" readonly value="<?php echo $nroviajex; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="IMO">Buque:</label>
    <select name="IMO" required id="IMO" class="form-control">
    <option value=" "> Seleccione el buque </option>
    <?php echo $opcion; ?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="PTOPROCEDENCIA">Puerto de Procedencia:</label>
    <select name="PTOPROCEDENCIA" id="PTOPROCEDENCIA" class="form-control">
    <option value=" "> Seleccione un puerto de procedencia </option>
        <option value=" Aachen  "> Aachen </option>
        <option value=" Aalesund    "> Aalesund </option>
        <option value=" Aarhus  "> Aarhus </option>
        bla bla bla
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="PAISPROCEDENCIA">País de Procedencia:</label>     
    <select required name="PAISPROCEDENCIA" class="form-control">
      <option value="   ">Seleccione un país de procedencia </option>
        <option value=" Afganistán  "> Afganistán </option>
        <option value=" Akrotiri    "> Akrotiri </option>
        <option value=" Albania "> Albania </option>
        bla bla bla
      </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="PTODESTINO">Puerto de Destino:</label>
    <select name="PTODESTINO" required class="form-control" id="PTODESTINO">
    <option value=" "> Seleccione un puerto de destino </option>
        <option value=" Aachen  "> Aachen </option>
        <option value=" Aalesund    "> Aalesund </option>
        <option value=" Aarhus  "> Aarhus </option>
        bla bla bla
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="PAISDESTINO">País de Destino:</label>      
    <select required name="PAISDESTINO" class="form-control">
      <option value="   ">Seleccione un país de destino</option>
        <option value=" Afganistán  "> Afganistán </option>
        <option value=" Akrotiri    "> Akrotiri </option>
        <option value=" Albania "> Albania </option>
        bla bla bla
      </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Tipo de Operación:</label>
    <br>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="OPERACION" value="CARGA" id="OPERACION_0" required>
      Carga</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="OPERACION" value="DESCARGA" id="OPERACION_1">
      Descarga</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="CARGA">Cargamento:</label>
    <select name="CARGA" required id="CARGA" class="form-control">
    <option value=" ">  Seleccione el cargamento     </option>
    <option value=" 150N    ">  150N     </option>
<option value=" 150N/CHEVRONTEXACO  ">  150N/CHEVRONTEXACO   </option>
<option value=" 150N/SHELL  ">  150N/SHELL   </option>
bla bla bla

    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="CANTIDAD">Cantidad (BBLS):</label>
    <input name="CANTIDAD" type="number" required id="CANTIDAD" min="1" class="form-control">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="CHARTER">Charter (Cliente):</label>
    <select name="CHARTER" required id="CHARTER" class="form-control">
    <option value=" "> Seleccione el charter (cliente) </option>
    <?php echo $opcionch; ?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="Enviar" id="Enviar" value="Enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
  </p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este el código de mi formulario y logro mostrar sin problema alguno en el "Select IMO", una lista de los buques cada uno con su nombre e IMO, sin embargo estoy buscando una forma de al usar el botón de submit, se guarde en el nuevo elemento de la tabla viajes, no solamente el IMO del buque seleccionado, eso lo he logrado sin problemas, sino también el nombre del buque que tiene ese IMO, sin tener que seleccionarlo de alguna forma adicional en el formulario.

De la manera que estoy intentando hacerlo en mi codigo, en efecto, se crea un nuevo registro en la tabla, pero el campo "buque" se queda en blanco y obtengo el siguiente error: *Notice: Undefined index: elbuque in C:\xampp\htdocs\agente-nav-online\agregar-viaje.php on line 16*

Agradecería toda la ayuda posible.

Comment: Aquí $buquedeimo=$buquedeimox["elbuque"]; te quedas con el campo elbuque, pero aquí: ..select NOMBRE from buques as elbuque.. elbuque no es un campo sino una tabla, ¿no será así la sql? ...select NOMBRE as elbuque from buques where...

Comment: Correcto, otro usuario me hizo esa corrección en SO en inglés y me sirvió a la perfección. De igual manera puedes colocar la respuesta y la marcaré como la solución a mi pregunta.